# Testing SWFUpload with Cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, swfupload

In a project, I recently replaced a simple form-based file upload with SWFUpload.  When SWFUpload returns a success, I generate a form to add tags to the uploaded asset.

I'd like to be able to test inputting data into the tags textbox, but to do that I (think I) need to fake out SWFUpload.

Has anyone done this in the past?  I haven't been able to find anything via google, and there doesn't seem to be anything in the cucumber docs re: testing Flash.

Comment: I was unable to get the auth token to work, although I haven't put much effort into it at this point.  Judging from your comment, you haven't gotten it working either?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you need to fake flash at all, because all swfupload is doing for you is simulating a simple http post.

If you do a manual http post to the same action/controller that your swfupload is posting to and make sure the file field of your post is named the same as the swf parameter which swfupload passes (params[:Filedata]) you should get the same effect.

Also to answer Swanand's comment above you need to hack CGI::Session. Try http://blog.isshen.com/2008/10/5/making-swfupload-and-rails-2-1-sessions-work-together

Answer (score 0):

I recently stumbled upon [this plugin](http://wiki.github.com/aslakhellesoy/cucumber/funfx-and-flex) which may be able to help you with what yo need to do.  You can read more [here](http://wiki.github.com/peternic/funfx).